# If I placed a converging lens in water, would its surface power change?

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

If I placed a converging lens in water, would its surface power change ?
The first case when the lens is in air then placed in water; does the surface power change or remain the same?

Comment: Yes, the index of refraction of the media of immersion matters: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/surpow.html

Comment: And adding to Peter Diehr's comment, THAT is why objects underwater look blurry without a mask ... the focal point of your eye shifts substantially when water is on your cornea rather than air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [lensmaker's formula states](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenmak.html)

$$P_{lens}=\frac{n_{\rm{lens}}-n_{0}}{n_{0}}\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right)$$

This shows that the power of the lens does indeed depend on the refractive index of the medium ($n_0$) in which the lens is placed. In the extreme case where $n_{\rm{lens}}=n_0$, the lens will have no power at all.